# How to login in ur app by facebook

Tags: ios, facebook

I have to add feature to login with facebook. I dont know the approach to use facebook login i mean as in basic login we store user name and password on backend. but in case of facebook login what will do i.e what value we store on server?

Suppose i have login by facebook in my app then something should be saved on server. and then i logout from app and on some other day again i login from faecbook with same credential then as we can not store facebook user name and password on server . so what value will be saved on server so that server will identify that this is the same user who logged 1-2 day ago i.e its not a new user.

ok i am explaining the process. Suppose first time login with facebook then i will get some info like access token, userid, etc then i have to store one thing in my User table on server which will have list of all user of app right? so my question was which thing i can save on my user table as a user name so that when then same user will login into my app with same facebook credential, then again i will get some user info and i will check in my user table to know that is it a new user or old user right? if every time on facebook login i will be creating new user then users will not be able to access old account of the app(not facebook, they will lost all the things they done with their old account i.e when logged in first time). so i wanted to know that my approach is right or not and if right then which value i can store in my user table to identify it as a unique user.. Thanks

Can any one please explain me the process of facebook login?

Thanks

Comment: Better use facebook API in your app for login instead of asking user to enter facebook credentials in your app. You can use auth token returned by facebook for other purposes.

Comment: i dnt want to ask user facebook credentials. i will use facebook api and on login the facebook login popup will open and then  i wanted to know the process after login. so you mean i will get auth token and i can store that as user name right? so every time the auth token will be same for one user right?

Comment: Facebook provides an auth token that is valid for 60 days usually and Facebook returns same token if user logs in again.

Comment: so if a user login on 61st day then auth token will be different then how our server will recognize the old users?

Comment: Facebook cant give you access to user's account forever. User has  to login again after a specified time. You can ask Facebook for an extended token which might last a bit longer. If you can specify for what purpose you want to store user credentials, I might help you better.

Comment: You can also ask Facebook to renew token once its expired.

Comment: ok i am explainging the process.

Comment: please chek my update question

Comment: Facebook stores a uniques user-id for each user. So on login you can query and store id of the user which would never change for the same account. For details check [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/user-data-ios-sdk/)

Comment: Thanks a lot thata what i wanted to clear, so i can user either userid or facebookid which is like that 123845132 (this id is unique for each user).. right?

Comment: Exactly. If user have set it, it might be alphanumeric. Ex. john2333 but it would always be unique and same for one account.

Comment: I put my comment as answer. Please do accept it if it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook stores a uniques user-id for each user. So on login you can query and store id of the user which would never change for the same account. For details check [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/user-data-ios-sdk/).

Answer (score 0):

You can take user's facebook Id and store it on your server and Identify that it's new user or not.

Answer (score 0):

you can login with facebook using facebook sdk or ios native facebook . you will get user name ,user id  and user detail , these detail you can save at your end or server side.